# Generate a text message similar to the Volume OSD?

Tags: notifications, window-manager

Is there a way to create a message similar to the Volume OSD (window-less) from automator or a command-line app?

I'm using the Mac to "remote control" the media player on a (headless) raspberry pi (ssh, automator quick actions & keyboard shortcuts).  I'd like to be able to fetch the title of the currently playing song (easy enough) and display it (transient) without creating a window ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after lots of googling and reading I didn't find a reasonable way to achieve what I was asking for; instead I came up with a work-around.

I employed `osascript` for this particular job - not quite what I actually wanted, but an acceptable substitute:

```
cat /usr/local/bin/notify
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/osascript -e "display alert \"$*\" giving up after 5"
```

In case anyone is interested in how the rest of the stack works:

In my home on the `pi` I have this:

```
cat xmshow
#!/bin/bash
xmms2 list| awk '/^->/{gsub(/^[^\]]+\] /,"");gsub(/ \([0-9:]+)$/,"");print;nextfile}'
```

On the Mac:

```
cat xmshow
title=$(ssh -i  ~/.ssh/torti pi@my.pi.ip /home/pi//bin/xmshow)
/usr/local/bin/notify $title >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And the following Quick Action workflow:

[image: Automator]

which I then tied to:

[image: Keyboard shortcut]

giving me this in action:

[image]